# Why is AsyncSelect only showing options once?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to make use of `<AsyncSelect />` to pull options from an API to populate a form.

It works find the first time I search for something, I can select the option and am then prompted to type again.

However when I type something else, I get `No Options` even though I can see the data show up in a console.log().

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

type State = {
  inputValue: string,
};

const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(
        fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(rjson => {
          return rjson.map(c => {
            return { name: c.name, label: c.name}
          })
        })
      );
    }, 1000);
  });

export default class AsyncMulti extends Component<*, State> {
  state = { inputValue: '' };
  handleInputChange = (newValue: string) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    return inputValue;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <AsyncSelect
        isMulti
        loadOptions={promiseOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the object being returned in the Promise:

```
{ name: c.name, label: c.name }
```

had the wrong keys, and should have been:

```
{ value: c.name, label: c.name }
```

And it works now.